# Can we call Spotify api BufferAnalyzer using Android code

Tags: android, audio-streaming, spotify

I want to get audio data of the currently streaming music via Apotify. I want to call BufferAnalyzer(https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/api-audio-bufferanalyzer.html) to get audio data. Is it possible to call it using Android code?

Answer (score 2):

No. The Apps API you reference is only available to HTML/JavaScript apps running inside the Spotify desktop client.

Comment: Thank you. Can I get audio data of the currently streamed music via Spotify using Android/iOS code?